# Calculating angle to aim at target results in over/under aim depending on whether target is below/above

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

I'm calculating the angle (in radians, ranges -3.141 to 3.141 for yaw and -1.343 to 1.396 for pitch) to aim at in order to aim at a target position. The data I have is my local world camera position, and the world target position. The result should be the angle that needs to be set in order to aim precisely at the target.

This is a fairly simple calculation (even though I'm terrible at math) and it works without issue.. but it has a quirk when I'm in third person.

When I'm in first person, the "local world camera position" is effectively my player's eye position. When I'm in third person the "local world camera position" is effectively offset backwards and above from my player's eye position.

The quirk (actually a pretty big flaw right now) is that when the target position is elevated higher than my local world camera position, the result of my calculation results in an angle that over-shoots/over-aims the target. Inversely, when the target position is elevated lower than my local world camera position, the result of my calculation results in an angle that under-shoots/under-aims the target.

I've drawn this very bad sketch to try and explain my issue, for clarity my drawing is 2D and drawn from the side, but my application is 3D: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ucEA.png

And to clear something up, the further my angle is pitched downwards, the closer my camera position will be to the top of my local player and the further my angle is pitched upwards, the closer my camera will be to the bottom of my local player. If you imagine playing a third person game you should understand what I mean.

Here's the calculation I'm doing:

`Vector3 vForwardVector = vTargetPosition - vCameraPosition;
Vector2 vCalculatedAngle = Vector2(atan2(vForwardVector.x, vForwardVector.z), atan2(vForwardVector.y, sqrt(vForwardVector.x * vForwardVector.x + vForwardVector.z * vForwardVector.z)));`

The only other thing I can mention that I noticed is that the erroneous effect is less-so the longer the distance between camera position and target position. It is most extreme when the target position is very close to the camera position.

I'm not sure what other detail I can provide.. hoping someone can point out an obvious mistake? Happy to provide any extra information!

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Are you trying to find the angles from the camera, then? How does the coordinate system in your code snippet relate to the sketch?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the -77 degree to + 80 degree limits on the pitch?

Comment: @amd I'm sorry, the sketch completely mismatches the coordinate system, I just included it in the off chance someone would see where I was coming from with it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair the engine I'm working with enforces that limit, I would assume to stop players from being able to look directly above, or directly below, their player model.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I deleted my original post, since I once again forgot that `atan2` traditionally takes its arguments in reverse: To find the angle from the positive $x$-axis to the point $(x, y)$ you need `atan2(y,x)` - another matter I'd personally like to beat some sense into some early programmer about.

Looking over it again, I note that the calculation works in first person. That alone should have told me that I had mistaken the cause. The formulas you gave are okay. The problem appears to me that you are misunderstanding something about the situation. I can only guess what it is, but most likely, *it is that the scene is not rotating about an axis through the camera*. In your calculation, the camera is located at the origin. The yaw rotation is about the vertical (y) axis, and the pitch rotation is about the transverse (x) axis. But usually in third person view, it is still the local player at the origin, not the camera.

I think what you want to do is to find the rotations from the player's point of view - i.e., what you would get if you were in first person mode. Those are the same angles you need in third person mode. But this depends on exactly how the game engine works, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't resolve the problem :( In fact, without an additional fix in place, the resulting pitch angle from this calculation would be outside of the bounds I mentioned. And yes, the axis' being swapped is something specific to this game engine - and unfortunately I must work within the limits of the game engine. I suppose as you mentioned, it is a design decision made early on (for reasons I am not aware of) that they decided to live with.

From my description of the problem, is there nothing else you could theorize as to being the cause?

Comment: It's common to have the $z$-axis in the camera’s coordinate system aligned with the camera’s axis so that it’s not much of a mental leap to go from $x$ and $y$ there to $x$ and $y$ in the image plane. The coordinate system here might be set up that way to avoid a big rotation when converting to camera space.

Comment: @user7716080 - I replaced the original answer. I had forgotten that it is `atan2(y,x)` not `atan2(x,y)`. However, I am pretty sure I know what your problem is. Whether I've found the fix is less clear.